# The bookmarks sidebar in Firefox seems to be rendered in HTML

Tags: firefox, html, css

This rule in a userstylesheet I use seem to affect it:

```
*[id*='related'], *[id*='side'], *[role*="complementary"], *[id*='Panel'],  *[id*='Layout'] {
    visibility:hidden !important;
}
```

**Before:**
[image: 1]

**After:**
[image]

So, is there any documentation of its HTML?

**Edit::** And can I exclude it by `@-moz-document regexp()`?

**Workaround**:: prefix `body` on all selectors (`body [id*='related'],`...) to restrict applying only on webpages. (apparently sidebar doesn't live inside a `<body>` tag) [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rCd5b/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox's interface is written in XUL which is a form of XML. It's markup is almost identical to HTML with some other advantages, particularly for add-on devs.

To view the code that constructs the user interface, open a new tab and go to `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`. This will display your web browser's interface inside the web browser. Then, use Firefox's built-in web dev tools to inspect the markup or press Ctrl+U to view the source.

It's so damn easy to edit, even for someone with little to no programming knowledge. This is why I love Firefox. You can live-edit the CSS and when you're happy with the changes, use [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) to make a new style (blank style, using the XUL namespace) and save it.

Comment: [Similarly, where's the "Restore Session" page's XUL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322056/where-is-firefoxs-restore-session-pages-xul)